# How to count the rows from 1 table but from two different column

Tags: sql-server, select, count

```
SELECT distinct Major, COUNT(Major) AS MajorCount FROM 
[College Management System].[dbo].[ApplicantCourseDetails]
group by Major 

SELECT distinct MinorI, COUNT(MinorI) AS MinorCount FROM 
[College Management System].[dbo].[ApplicantCourseDetails]
group by MinorI
```

### Result should be like this.

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   Major   ║ MajorCount ║   MinorI   ║ MinorCount ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Botany    ║ 1          ║            ║            ║
║ Chemistry ║ 2          ║ Chemistry  ║ 2          ║
║ English   ║ 2          ║ English    ║ 2          ║
║ History   ║ 2          ║ History    ║ 1          ║
║           ║            ║ Philosophy ║ 1          ║
║           ║            ║ Zoology    ║ 1          ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard syntax

Comment: both of these query are giving me the result i want..all i want is, write only 1 query instead of two select query

Comment: UNION ALL would work, concat some text if you want to know which is which.

Comment: union all is not giving me the output i want..sub query might give me the right output..but how to write a sub query for this???

Comment: Sample data and expected output will make it easier to understand what you are locking for.

Comment: Can you please add in question how the output of the combined query will be?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98afc/1

Comment: as output i want four column Major, MajorCount, MinorI and Minor Count

Comment: I don't use Windows (haven't used SQL Server since ~ 2000), but couldn't you use two WITH clauses and then combine the results from those into a single INSERT statement? If I've understood your requirements correctly - you haven't posted your desired result anywhere.

Comment: In the result there should not be any null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a cross apply and values to create a row for each value and an extra column in the values clause to keep track of what value is a major and what value is a minor.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98afc/36)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ApplicantCourseDetail(
    [Major] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MinorI] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
INSERT INTO ApplicantCourseDetail
           ([Major]
           ,[MinorI])
     VALUES
           ('Chemistry','History'),
('English','Chemistry'),
('Botany','Zoology'),
('History','English'),
('Chemistry','Chemistry'),
('English','Philosophy'),
('History','English')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T.Value,
       count(case when T.IsMajor = 1 then A.Major end) as MajorCount,
       count(case when T.IsMajor = 0 then A.MinorI end) as MinorCount
from dbo.ApplicantCourseDetail as A
  cross apply (values (A.Major, 1),(A.MinorI, 0)) as T(Value, IsMajor)
group by T.Value;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98afc/36/0)**:

```
|      VALUE | MAJORCOUNT | MINORCOUNT |
|------------|------------|------------|
|     Botany |          1 |          0 |
|  Chemistry |          2 |          2 |
|    English |          2 |          2 |
|    History |          2 |          1 |
| Philosophy |          0 |          1 |
|    Zoology |          0 |          1 |
```

Comment: much much better result..thanks Mikael Eriksson

Comment: mikael i also want to add more column in output Total, in which the sum of majorcount and minor count ll displayed..Eg. Botany total should be 1, chemistry total ll be 4 n so on..

Comment: @Dchauhan just add a column that counts all rows. `count(*) as Total`.

Comment: done..its working like a charm

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT  Major, COUNT(Major) AS MajorCount 
FROM #ApplicantCourseDetail
group by Major) A 
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT MinorI, COUNT(MinorI) AS MinorCount 
FROM #ApplicantCourseDetail
group by MinorI)B
ON A.Major = B.MinorI
```

### Result

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   Major   ║ MajorCount ║   MinorI   ║ MinorCount ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Botany    ║ 1          ║ NULL       ║ NULL       ║
║ Chemistry ║ 2          ║ Chemistry  ║ 2          ║
║ English   ║ 2          ║ English    ║ 2          ║
║ History   ║ 2          ║ History    ║ 1          ║
║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║ Philosophy ║ 1          ║
║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║ Zoology    ║ 1          ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

---

### Update

```
SELECT ISNULL(Major, '')       AS Major
      ,ISNULL(CAST(MajorCount AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS MajorCount 
      ,ISNULL(MinorI , '')     AS MinorI
      ,ISNULL(CAST(MinorCount AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS MinorCount
 FROM
(SELECT  Major, COUNT(Major) AS MajorCount 
FROM #ApplicantCourseDetail
group by Major) A 
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT MinorI, COUNT(MinorI) AS MinorCount 
FROM #ApplicantCourseDetail
group by MinorI)B
ON A.Major = B.MinorI
```

### Result

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   Major   ║ MajorCount ║   MinorI   ║ MinorCount ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Botany    ║          1 ║            ║            ║
║ Chemistry ║          2 ║ Chemistry  ║          2 ║
║ English   ║          2 ║ English    ║          2 ║
║ History   ║          2 ║ History    ║          1 ║
║           ║            ║ Philosophy ║          1 ║
║           ║            ║ Zoology    ║          1 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: this is what i'm lookin for.. but how can i avoid these null values

Comment: You cannot avoid nulls as Both queries return different values and getting them in together in same result set will result in some null values.

Comment: @DChauhan have a look now I have updated my answer